# iOS Facebook SDK - sort friends by "importance" or last-contacted date?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the Facebook SDK for iOS. Grabbing list of friends using `/me/friends` graph API.

Is there anyway to sort friends by "importance" (i.e the last time you contacted them, or how often you contact them)?